# Angular 6 - http get request response mapping to object

Tags: angular, class, http, dictionary, request

I have JSON file which try to load by get http request and map for
model class.

I have JSON file

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Dan1",
    "lastName": "Dan1"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Dan2",
    "lastName": "Dan2"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Dan3",
    "lastName": "Dan4"
  }
]
```

I have model code like this:

```
export class Record {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

and component like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Record} from './models/record';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'CRM';
  apiUrl = './assets/test.json';
  itemList: Array<Record>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    const obs = this.http.get<Record[]>(this.apiUrl, {responseType: 'json'});
    obs.subscribe((records: Record[]) => {
      this.itemList = records;
    });

  }
}
```

Questions:

1. Why **this.itemList** is not Array of Record despite the fact that I use: `this.http.get<Record[]>` and `(records: Record[])`. Is that mean Angular will not map JSON on Array of Record ? If yes what for are those definitions ?
2. Is there any way I can do this without manual creating this object and put it into array  ?

Answer (score 0):

The itemList is not an array of `Record` because `TypeScript` is basically javascript with typings for the compiler. The compiler just checks. If you say that `http.get` returns a `Record[]`, then the compiler believes you that the returned object will have that structure.

It's up to you to actually make it an Record array. Which is quite easy, and needs to be done manually, just like you would do in JavaScript:

```
obs.pipe(
  map((records) => records.map((record) => Object.assign(new Record(), record)))
).subscribe((records: Record[]) => {
  this.itemList = records;
});
```

A little advice though, look into the `async` pipe. This way you don't have to subscribe inside your component, and it all looks just a bit neater.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
this.itemList = records.map(r => Object.create(new Record(), r);
```

as for why? because I guess.